# MS Access Custom Reference ID field with formatted AutoNumber

Tags: ms-access, formatting

Sorry for the basic question, I'm an absolute newbie to Microsoft Access.

I am trying to create a calculated field in a table that uses the AutoNumber'ed ID field and another field to create a reference number for the row.

i.e. I have an ID field which is AutoNumber type with a "UMLINSP-"000 format which yields UMLINSP-001, UMLINSP-002, etc.

I have another field with codes (which change each row) - AZE, GUN, ZAR, etc.

I want to now create a field which joins these two to create UMLINSP-001-AZE, UMLINSP-002-GUN, etc.

However, when I create a calculated field that references these two fields, I get UMLINSP-1-AZE, UMLINSP-2-GUN.  The 000 format of the ID field does not get transferred.

I understand why this would be (the format only displays the ID in 000 format, doesn't actually convert it) but I would like to know how this can be achieved with the correct method.

Any and all help is highly appreciated!

Comment: can you share the query or expression which you have treid until now.

Comment: @Tarun.P [ID] & "-" & [Code] yields "UMLINSP-1-AZE" which is no good.  I tried to keep [ID] as a simple AutoNumber (1,2,3,etc) and tried "UMLINSP-" & Format([ID],"000") & "-" & [Code] but seems like the Format() function cannot be used in a calculated field in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably concatenating values *similar* to:

```
"UMLINSP-" & 1 & "-AZE"
```

Use *Format* to obtain your desired value:

```
"UMLINSP-" & Format(1, "000") & "-AZE"
```

As Format property for a table field, it would be:

```
"UMLINSP-"000"-AZE"
```

For changing values, use a query and an expression like:

```
CustomID: [FieldHoldingPrefix] & Format([ID], "\-000\-") & [FieldHoldingSuffix]
```

Comment: Normally this would work in a query but in a table Format() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the problem is that each row is different, not all should have a "-AZE" suffix.  The suffix depends on the data in the "Code" field.  That's why I'm trying to concatenate the fields, rather than just a format as you suggested.

Comment: Then you must use a query. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge you cannot achieved your result using table `Format` property.

but you can achieve this using query as below

```
'UMLINSP-'+CStr(Format([ID_CODE],'000')) & '-' & [Code] AS Mew_ID
```

use above code in query than you will get the reuslt which you like to achieve.